# Plotting the set $\left\{ z\in \mathbb{C} : \left| z+i \right| =2\left| z \right| \right\} $

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions, complex-geometry

I have a question which can be simple, though I couldn't catch the idea.

Consider the Set given below:

$$E=\left\{ z\in \mathbb{C} : \left| z+i \right| =2\left| z \right|  \right\} $$

I have to find its graph to plot.

The Answer is the following: **the Set $E$ is a circle, centred at $i/3$ and of radius $2/3$**

I was not able of visualizing this set, I absurdly thought about a spiral. Any calculations neither didn't lead me to a solution. *And especially, my conclusion was that this graph couldn't be a circle at all.*

Thanks for helping me in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius

Comment: $x^2+(y+1)^2=2x^2+2y^2$ in cartesian plan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint

Put $z=x+yi$ in given equation to get $$x^2+(y+1)^2=4(x^2+y^2)$$
$$\Rightarrow 3(x^2+y^2)-2y-1=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2+y^2-\frac 23 y-\frac 13=0$$
Which is the equation of required circle with centre $(0,\frac 13)$ and radius $\frac 23$ but since we are dealing in complex plane the centre is $\frac i3$

Comment: Thank you. I achieved the same calculation until the last line, but I couldn't gather any conclusion out of it.

Comment: @bugrahaskan Well for any general equation of circle like $$x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$ The center of the circle is $(-g, -f) $ and radius $$r=\sqrt {g^2+f^2-c}$$. In our case $g=0,f=-\frac 13, c=-\frac 13$

Comment: @bugrahaskan I think its taught in analytics geometry, ie cartesian coordinates

Comment: Indeed, I'm reviewing my Analysis in parallel with Real and Complex. Some times they aren't synchrinous.

Answer (score 5):

A good way to read an equation like this is geometrically. We want all points such that their distance from $-i$ is two times their distance from $0$. It should be clear that both $i$ and $-\frac13i$ both satisfy this condition. What ever the set looks like, it must be symmetric across the line through $-i$ and $0$, which is to say, the imaginary axis.

To see that the desired set is a circle is a little trickier. The general such problem is the Circles of Appollonius problem, which is linked in a comment under your question. A more modern approach is to follow Descartes, and write down an equation in $x$ and $y$ satisfied by points in the desired set. This equation is also given in a comment under your question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a "non-Cartesian" solution with a complex square completion.

The equation of a circle in the complex plane around point $a$ is:

- $|z-a|^2 = (z-a)(\bar z - \bar a)= |z|^2 - 2 Re(\bar a z) + |a|^2 = r^2$

Squaring the given equation:

- $|z|^2 - 2 Re(i z) + 1 = 4 |z|^2$

Rearranging and square completing:

- $|z|^2 - 2 Re(-\frac{i}{3} z) - \frac{1}{3} = |z - \frac{i}{3} |^2 - \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{3}= 0$
  $$ \rightarrow |z -\frac{i}{3}| = \frac{2}{3}$$